# Output an image file from a servlet

Tags: java, servlets

How to serve an image, stored on my hard drive, in a servlet?
For Example:
I have an image stored in path `'Images/button.png'` and I want to serve this in a servlet with the URL `file/button.png`.

Comment: Do you know the importance of `Content-Type` that is set to `image/png` or whatever you need as mentioned in the following answer?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

- map a servlet to the `/file` url-pattern
- read the file from disk
- write it to `response.getOutputStream()`
- set the `Content-Type` header to `image/png` (if it is only pngs)

Answer (score 54):

Here is the working code:

```
 public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {

      ServletContext cntx= req.getServletContext();
      // Get the absolute path of the image
      String filename = cntx.getRealPath("Images/button.png");
      // retrieve mimeType dynamically
      String mime = cntx.getMimeType(filename);
      if (mime == null) {
        resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        return;
      }

      resp.setContentType(mime);
      File file = new File(filename);
      resp.setContentLength((int)file.length());

      FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
      OutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();

      // Copy the contents of the file to the output stream
       byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
       int count = 0;
       while ((count = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {
         out.write(buf, 0, count);
      }
    out.close();
    in.close();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another very simple way.

```
File file = new File("imageman.png");
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", resp.getOutputStream());
```

Comment: This is very inefficient as it unnecessarily parses the image into a `BufferedImage` object. This step is not needed if you don't want to manipulate the image (resize, crop, transform, etc). The fastest way is to just stream the bytes unmodified from the image input to the response output.