# Are web applications able to load images in this case?

Tags: java, web-applications

I have a Java Web Application on JBoss, I need to access images in a directory on the server, but cannot be accessed by URL. My question, is it possible that the web application can load these images? How I can do this?

Thank you in advance. (Sorry if my english is bad =P)

Comment: Have you placed those Images in JBOSS/bin/your-images-foldername folder? Which UI are using I mean JSP or ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the file from the location and write out via a servlet. see this: [Output an image file from a servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8623709/output-an-image-file-from-a-servlet)

Answer (score 0):

As long as you define the location of your resources in your classpath, you should be able to access these files.