# "Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:....jpg" Java EE Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, storage

I'm trying to retrieve a picture from my file system after a good storage,(instead of putting it in the database I copy it to the disc and i put the path to the db)

1. I had store the picture to c:\images\ folder and supposing that the name the complete path       is c:\images\mypic.jpg
2. when I try to retrieve it a set the img src attribute to `<img src="c:\images\mypic.jps">` by using some java code
3. in the browser console I found this error `Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C://images//mypic.jpg`

**Question:** how to fix these path problem ? where Should I store the pictures ? and from where should I retrieve them ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

sending tag `<img src="c:\images\mypic.jpg">` would cause user browser to access image from his filesystem. 
if you have to store images in folder located in `c:\images` i would suggest to create an servlet like images.jsp, that as a parameter takes name of a file, then sets servlet response content to an image/jpg and then loads bytes of image from server location and put it to a response.

But what you use to create your application? is it pure servlet? Spring? JSF?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8623709/output-an-image-file-from-a-servlet) you can find some info about, how to do it.

Comment: Cant help you with that. I haven't use it yet. But look around and im sure you will find a tutorial about sending image content via zk framework.
P.S. you should be able to write in your application pure servlet method with that functionality

Answer (score 11):

In Chrome, you are supposed to be able to allow this capability with a runtime flag --allow-file-access-from-files

However, it looks like there is a problem with current versions of Chrome (37, 38) where this doesn't work unless you also pass the runtime flag --disable-web-security

That's an unacceptable solution, except perhaps as a short-term workaround, but it has been identified as an issue:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=379206

Comment: Not only in chrome, other browsers such as Mozilla and Edge for MS all don't serve the images. I am working on a WordPress project and i get the same not allowed to load images error.

Comment: Both flags `--allow-file-access-from-files` and 
`--disable-web-security` doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 3):

You have Two alternatives :

First one is to create a ServletImageLoader that would take as a parameter an identifier of your image (the path of the image or a hash) that you will use inside the Servlet to handle your image, and it will print to the response stream the loaded image from the server.

Second one is to create a folder inside your application's ROOT folder and just save the relative path to your images.

Comment: I think the second is good,please could you clarify how ? 
                                     
-I mean where to find the ROOT of my application ?

-what is the path to put pictures there ?
-and what is the path to retrieve ?

Answer (score 3):

Many browsers have changed their security policies to no longer allow reading data directly from file shares or even local resources. You need to either place the files somewhere that your tomcat instance can serve them up and put a "regular" http url in the html you generate. This can be accomplished by either providing a servlet which reads and provides the file putting the file into a directory where tomcat will serve it up as "static" content.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple `expressjs` solution if you just want to run this app locally and security is not a concern:

On your `server.js` or `app.js` file, add the following:

```
app.use('/local-files', express.static('/'));
```

That will serve your ENTIRE root directory under `/local-files`. Needless to say this is a really bad idea if you're planning to deploy this app anywhere other than your local machine.

Now, you can simply do:

```
<img src="/local-files/images/mypic.jps"/>
```

*note: I'm running macOS. If you're using Windows you may have to search and remove 'C:\' from the path string*

Answer (score 1):

The concept of http location and disk location is different. What you need to do is:

1. for uploaded file `summer.jpg`
2. move that under a known (to the application) location to disk, e.g `c:\images\summer.jpg`
3. insert into db record representing the image with text `summer.jpg`
4. to display it use plain `<img src="images/summer.jpg" />`
5. you need something (e.g apache) that will serve `c:\images\` under your application's `/images`. If you cannot do this then in step #2 you need to save somewhere under your web root, e.g `c:\my-applications\demo-app\build\images`

Comment: You can do it with apache with `Alias` or you can do it with tomcat (or whatever container you use) with a `ServletImageLoader` as Mifmif said.

Comment: could you clarify the Alias method please ,because i'm using zk framework ,I couldn't user the servletImageLoader I think

Comment: Google: `apache alias` for a first idea.

Answer (score 1):

This error means you can not directly load data from file system because there are security issues behind this. The only solution that I know is create a web service to serve load files.

Comment: I am using an apache server and it still did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use ABSOLUTE PATH to refer to the name of the image for example: `C:/xamp/www/Archivos/images/templatemo_image_02_opt_20160401-1244.jpg`. You must use the reference to its location within webserver. For example using `../../Archivos/images/templatemo_image_02_opt_20160401-1244.jpg` depending on where your process is running.