# Azure WebMatrix (pictures not loading on site)

Tags: html, css, azure

I am using webmatrix to run my website at the moment. Although not everything on my site is loading correctly. I have to pictures on my site that have a directory to my local machine but i would like to know how i can change it to some azure directory that will allow the pictures to appear on my site. If you hit f12 and scroll down on the site you will see near the bottom, the two pictures that are not loading. Any thoughts?

My site: http://rootforsite.azurewebsites.net/

```
<div class="imagess"> <img src="C:\Users\alex\Desktop\rootforsite\img\pic.jpg" class="img-    responsive center-block"  /> </div>
                </div>
    </div>
    <div class="imagess"> <img src="C:\Users\alex\Desktop\rootforsite\img\pic11.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block" style="margin-top: 10px;" /> </div>
    <iframe width="540" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/mb6SNytt5YI"   frameborder="0" allowfullscreen style="margin-top: 70px;"></iframe>
</div>
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can do is load the image online.

I went on the console and saw it said "Not allowed to load local resource"

This is because you're trying to take the file from your local file-directory, but the site doesn't know that.

Either you can upload the image, or go through a series of steps [make a servlet]

Hopefully this link can help:

["Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:....jpg" Java EE Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23969953/not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-file-c-jpg-java-ee-tomcat)

Comment: I did what you said an it worked! Unfortunately the quality of the photos decreased immensely. How would i change the image back to the same quality setting?

Comment: It really depends on where you upload the photos and how, I suppose. I'm hot a huge expert when it comes this.