# How to write the same route to a file from differents files located on different folders

Tags: php, directory

Imagine that I have following folders and files:

- folder_a/

  - file_a.php
  - folder_a1

    - img_a1.png
  - folder_a2/

    - file_a2.php

Is there a way that I can write only one route to img_a1.png no matter if I am on file_a.php or file_a2.php?

This is what I'm doing now:

To access img_a1.png from file_a.php:

```
 <img src="folder_a1/img_a1.png"/>
```

To access img_a1.png from file_a2.php:

```
<img src="../folder_a1/img_a1.png"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your goals but, my answer may fit your requirement:

```
       define("IMG_DIR ","c://xampp/htdocs/project/folder_a/folder_a1/");
```

now you just write your code like that :

```
<img src="<?= IMG_DIR ;?>/img_a1.png">
```

now you don't need to specify the directories in every php file that in different categories also

I hope you can use this ^_^

Comment: I understand your point but is not working. Are you sure about <?= IMG_DIR ;?>

Comment: oh ! , i forgot to tell you that you can't write the path like this:
C:/xampp/htdocs/hyperstore/images/
if you use a local server use it like this :
http:localhost/your_project/images/
then it will work
for more information see this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23969953/not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-file-c-jpg-java-ee-tomcat

Comment: could you write the error message? right click ->inspect element -> console

Comment: define("IMG_DIR ","project/folder_a/folder_a1/"); try this according to your files name