# <a href="http://file://///> convert file:// to file// ---remove colon

Tags: html, href

I need to open filelink (network share in local) in the browser.

I use such code:

```
<a href="http://file://///server/localfolder">
```

It open link in the browser but convert it to such format:
file/////server/localfolder (remove colon).

This way browser don't open local folder. 
I have tried to change file:///// to file:// or file:/// or file://// . But colon stell removed by browser.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't specify more than one protocol definition as part of a URL schema. You shouldn't link to `file://` either, really, but if you absolutely must, just remove the `http://` definition as follows:

```
<a href="file:///server/localfolder">
```

You can read more about `file:` protocol, and in particular its implementation in the following links:

- [Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme)
- [Another SO question (with very good answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246053/how-can-i-create-a-link-to-a-local-file-on-a-locally-run-web-page)

Comment: BenM, thank you for your comment. If I remove the http:// it doesn't open a link at all by pressing at it.  Only right click, copy link and paste in the browser.

Comment: Yes, file:///. Doesn't work. Link is correct but no way to open by pressing it.

Comment: @inno.vlad Try it with 5 slashes, or just read through the question marked as duplicate by Quentin.

Comment: But it doesn't work with 5 slashes too. The solution in duplicated question is from 2013 y., probably something has changed. It doesn't work. Really.

Comment: @inno.vlad 1. What browser are you using? 2. Why does the date matter? It's a definition of a URL scheme, those things don't change, they're implemented differently in different browsers, though. 3. How do you mean 'doesn't work'? You're not able to click the link, you get a 404, or something else? Do you have any JS preventing click on the element?

Comment: Browser - JS and Chrome. Link exist and user able to press it but nothing has happen. goo.gl/UeP6uC

Comment: Check your error console.

Comment: Not allowed to load local resource:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23969953/not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-file-c-jpg-java-ee-tomcat

Comment: Yes, I see. Probably security issue. Thank you, BenM. Good luck and good day to you.

Comment: @inno.vlad No problem. If the answer helped, you may want to mark it as solved :)