# Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/bootstrap/images/banner.jpg

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have just started to run in this problem! I have seen a lot of your guys questions and tried a lot of solutions but none of them works for me! I tried loading chrome from the command prompt with the code to allow files but didn't work. Why is this showing up? Also i don't understand any of Ajax so if possible please answer in more detail!
This is the css :

```
div.jumbotron.hero{
  background-image:url(C:/Users/INFORMATIKA/Desktop/banner.jpg);
}
```

This is the html I am using to put the image in the back:

```
<div class="jumbotron hero">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-6 col-md-pull-3 get-it">
                    <h1 class="text-uppercase text-center"><strong>Mirësevini </strong></h1>
                    <p class="text-center" id="umire">në IB - Learning , web-aplikacionin e krijuar nga Islam Bekaj </p>
                    <p></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am using XAMPP and used bootstrap for the css!

Comment: Use firefox, I never managed to get that working in chrome

Comment: I didn't think of that, thank you so much!

Comment: You already look like you have a localhost, you should give more information like what kind of local stack you are using, how are you loading the webpage and stuff.

Comment: I am using Xampp.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: Dude i am saying i tried a lot of other answers from stackoverflow but none worked.Idk any other way to fix this!

Comment: You really need to include code samples if you want to be helped.

Answer (score 0):

sending tag `<img src="C:/xampp/htdocs/bootstrap/images/banner.jpg">` would cause user browser to access image from **his** filesystem, not your server. if you have to store images in folder located in `C:/xampp/htdocs/bootstrap/images/` i would suggest to create an servlet like images.jsp, that as a parameter takes name of a file, then sets servlet response content to an image/jpg and then loads bytes of image from server location and put it to a response.

Got this from ["Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:....jpg" Java EE Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23969953/not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-file-c-jpg-java-ee-tomcat)

Comment: Correct. Except the OP is using XAMPP and not Tomcat.