# Not allowed to load local resource in Html when image path is given

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring-mvc

```
   <img style="width:80px; height : 80px;" src="G:\Spring-Tutorial\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\contentmanagementsystem\resources\images\GoodBook.jpeg">
```

Above is my image url which points to image in my context path of my spring mvc project 
**\resources\images\GoodBook.jpeg**

but in console it gives error as follows and image is not appearing.

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///G:/Spring-Tutorial/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/contentmanagementsystem/resources/images/GoodBook.jpeg
```

I am new html with Spring MVC .please advise me in code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23969953/not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-file-c-jpg-java-ee-tomcat

Comment: image path is G:\Spring-Tutorial\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\contentmanagementsystem\resources\images\GoodBook.jpeg

Comment: the path is in project directory not in local drive.