# Image Display in JSP

Tags: image, jsp, servlets

How to display an image to jsp page ?
It does not allow me to display . 
I am using simple servlet application and I have mention the correct path so path is not the issue .

Provide the solution as soon as possible.

Comment: Please share your code and let us see what have you tried so far so that we can help to resolve the problem.

Comment: check your browser console for errors

Comment: I am giving the path of image , not from database and it shows the the message which I have written in src attribute of img tag instead of showing image . I also tried in other browser that is IE but same issue occurs.

Comment: Please share the suspicious portion of the code. "*it shows the the message which I have written in src attribute of img tag instead of showing image*". What do you mean by "*message*" in this context. The `src` attribute in `<img>` is meant for a relative path. Try looking into the generated HTML code. You might be giving a wrong path in the `src` attribute in `<img>`.

Answer (score 2):

`<img>` tag in `HTML` or `JSP`, will trigger a `GET` request which the server has to handle.

**EXAMPLE**

if I have image like below

```
 <img src="images?imageName=xyz.png"/>
```

the browser will request the `servlet` on the `server` with the name `images` passing the parameter `imageName and its value value`.

the `servlet images` has to handle the request and send image information in the form of stream which gets back to the browser and be displayed on the page.

**images is name given to a servlet**

follow this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8623709/output-an-image-file-from-a-servlet) for better understanding.

Comment: I cannot understand what you want to say .

what is images  
what is ?

Comment: `images` is the name of the `servlet` on the `server`. A request should have a `destination` and they do have `names`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for support .
Problem is solved.

The problem was :

I was trying to fetch the image file dynamically and was writing the height attribute so it was concatinate my src with height so I removed height and wrote before src attribute .

It Works .....