# image link which is located on my server using tomcat 8, java 8 webApp

Tags: tomcat, java-ee-7

I am using tomcat 8 to run my webApp created in intellij 14 and I want to make some link to uploaded image like `http://localhost:8080/images/profPic.jpeg` . but I don't know how to create this link. Where do I have to save images on server to make them accessible like this ?

> EDIT :

```
Context< docBase = "/some/path" path="some/link"/>
```

doesn't work. probably  they changed something in tomcat 8. Also, I know that putting files under web root makes them accessible  but in that case i need to deploy them on every change? i need to add and delete images dynamically

Comment: Perhaps it is a better idea to create a servlet that delivers your images instead of providing direct links

Comment: then how to put image in response and then display it ?

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8623709/output-an-image-file-from-a-servlet