# Not allowed to load local resource: in chrome tomcat

Tags: java, html, tomcat

html video tag is working when i make a normal html page and load the video in src
tag. When it comes to a jsp and accessing the video from video tag in localhost it 
is throwing the error as :-
Not allowed to load local resource:

What could be the solution to this.

Comment: How does your source param look like? If you reference to a local path this might cause the error. Can you provide a code snippet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Output an image file from a servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8623709/output-an-image-file-from-a-servlet)

Comment: Hey swinkler....here goes the code :-    <video width="320" height="240" controls><source src="D:/Videos/Bryce Dallas Howard Has a Calendar of Dad Ron Howard Sleeping - YouTube.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>

Comment: What is the workaround for this..really need some help here.Thanks

Comment: The problem is the "D:/Videos/...." - for security reasons the web server is not allowed to directly access the file system. See the other answer. one simple solution is to put the video(s) inside the web application you deploy under tomcat\webapps\<your webapp name>\yourvideo.mp4 and address it relatively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer . In order to access static resource from local host i just set the context doc base in the server xml of tomcat like this :-

```
<host><Context docBase="D:/Videos/" path="/videos" /></host>
```

by doing so you can access static resources from any drive then.
Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

Chrome does not allow local resources to be loaded by a web page due to security reasons.

You can serve the local resource from tomcat and use a relative path

```
 <source src="yourvideo.mp4"
```

Or you can disable security using the following chrome launch option `--allow-file-access-from-files`. By activating this option, Chrome will be able to load files locally.

```
> "C:\PathTo\Chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files
```

See alternatives and security considerations in this thread [How to launch html using Chrome at "--allow-file-access-from-files" mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586921/how-to-launch-html-using-chrome-at-allow-file-access-from-files-mode)