# Read an image file using okhttp3.RequestBody in java and send it to client using HTTPServletResponse

Tags: javascript, servlets

I tried to below code to send the response as byteStream, but I cannot read the image in my client side using Javascript.

Code to get image file:

```
Request getResponse = new Request.Builder()
             .URL("/getImage")
             .method("GET", null)
             .addHeader("Authorization", "oauthtoken " + accessToken).build();

Response response = client.newCall(getResponse).execute();
ResponseBody rBody = response.body().bytes();
```

I set the byteStream rBody to a jsonObject and send it to client using HTTPServletResponse like below.

```
{"file" : "����\u0000\u0010JFIF\u0000\u0001\u00..."};
```

But I cannot read the image file from the client side.

Comment: Why send it as JSON - it's a binary file? If for some reason your forced to send it in that format then it should be base64 encoded

Comment: There are no restriction in that. I chose JSON type. How can i send it as a binary file using HTTPServletResponse ?

Comment: Write the image [to the servlet output stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8623709/output-an-image-file-from-a-servlet)

Comment: Before you send it as HttpServletRedponse you have to send it as httpservlet request but this imposes a file uploading functionality on the server. You can't create a server on the client side, nor you have access to the file object which is restricted by the content security policy.

Comment: Nope, this is entirely unrelated to "file uploading functionality on the server".